# Illustrator to SWF AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to export an ai file an artist has given me to SWF AS3 format in Illustrator (so that I can load it into the GAF converter and put it into Unity3D).

Illustrator does indeed allow exporting of the file to SWF format, but chooses AS2 for the SWF rather than AS3 (the GAF converter requires AS3).  Having checked every bit, nibble and byte, there doesn't appear to be anything anywhere on the entire internet about this.

Any idea how to get illustrator to export SWF AS3?  Or do I need to go down a different route?

Comment: As Marc points out bellow, You can import the .ai file in the Flash Professional authoring tool. You also have some nice options on converting graphics to MovieClips so you can name them if that's of use. Another option would be using the [Embed] metadata to [embed an SVG](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fa4) your illustrator can easily save. You can compile the .as file with the Embed tag from commandline using mxmlc from the free FlexSDK for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming you have the Flash program: you could import the vectors (in any format) into Flash and then adjust the publish settings to AS3.